# Visual Studio 2022 & SubWCRev

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I would like to automatically add the repository version from Subversion to my software version. For that I found out that SubWCRev.exe could be used with the help of a pre-build event command.

I created a template: "AssemblyInfo.template.txt"

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.$WCREV$")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.$WCREV$")]
```

I Also added the pre-build event line:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe" "$(ProjectDir)." "$(ProjectDir)AssemblyInfo.template.txt" "$(ProjectDir)AssemblyInfo.cs"
```

The issue I face is that when I build the application, the Assembly.cs file is generated with the values in my Project.csproj file.

Is using "SubWCRev" obsolete for what I want to do? or should I do something differently?

I'm also wondering how the "pre-build event" could be updated to ensure it could work for other users on other PCs too.

Edit: If I create a random static class that contains a string variable with the revision number, it works but the program version is not set with the correct value in this way. At least it means the pre-built event works fine. It seems with newer version of Visual studio the assembly file is created when building. Should I try to modify the values my Project.csproj file? It feels as if it would be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SubWCRev" still works.  The process is largely the same as before.  The one missing piece is to set the following in the project's ".csproj" file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>blah blah blah</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This prevents the default generation of assembly info from project information.

Comment: That was indeed what I was missing! thank you! I searched quite a bit but did not find reference to this so thank you.